# A fair dice is rolled $n$ times with the results denoted as $R_i$ for $i=1,2,...,n$

Tags: probability

A fair dice is rolled $n$ times with the results denoted as $R_i$ for $i=1,2,...,n$, suppose each roll is independent, denote $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}R_i$

a) For fixed $n$, find the expectation of $S_n$

The answer wrote $$E(\sum_{i=1}^{n}R_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{6}(1+2+3+4+5+6)$$

can anyone explain to me the answer please because i am not sure what they are doing.

Comment: The answer is skipping one important part. Because of linearity of expectation you can say that $E S_n = E \sum_{i=1}^n R_i = \sum_{i=1}^n E R_i = n * E R_i$ then you are done.

Comment: Nit-pick: the singular of "dice" is "die".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single throw, the expectation is:
$$E(R_i) = \frac{1}{6} (1+2+3+4+5+6) $$
Expectation of a sum of independent variables is the sum of expectations,
$$E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$$
So for $n$ independent throws, the expectation of the sum of the outcomes will be
$$ E(\sum_{i=1}^n R_i ) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(R_i) $$

Comment: Actually the variables don't need to be independent to apply the linearity condition. i.e. For any two random variables $X$ and $Y$ the condition $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$ is true.

Comment: I wasn't sure, thank you for reminding me! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of linearity of expectation. This means that is you have a collection of random variables $R_1,...,R_n$ and you define $S = R_1 + ... + R_n$ then you have :
$$
\mathbb{E}[S] = \mathbb{E}[ R_1 + ... + R_n] =  \mathbb{E}[R_1] + ... +  \mathbb{E}[R_n]
$$